# If no index, then does it matter if it's nonsargable?

Tags: sql-server-2008, query-optimization

If I have a query with a condition

```
where year(MyColumn) = 2009
```

Since there is no index on MyColumn, will it matter if transform it to be 'sargeable'?

```
where MyColumn >= '20090101' and MyColumn < '20100101'
```

(Besides the overhead of the YEAR function call)

Comment: can you explain what you gain from writing it the non-sargable way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

code it for the index `where MyColumn >= 20090101 and MyColumn < 20100101`, you may add one some time in the future, but forget to fix this query to use it.

Comment: Exactly what I was going to say. Always use the query most likely to make use of an index. Just because there isn't an index now doesn't mean there won't be one tomorrow. What is so difficult about doing it the right way regardless? A few extra keystrokes?

Comment: Thank you, I was just wondering about the performance implications. Though I didn't actually think of making it future-proof.

Comment: @Gabe, I work in a database with over 1k tables. It is impossible to keep track of all the indexes, so I just always write the condition to use an index if it exists.  When I run the query, and it is too slow, I'll then check to see if one exists or not.